# Alignment and size guarantees for single member structs

Tags: c++, struct, alignment, sizeof

Given a (possibly-non-POD) `struct` with a single member, no inheritance, and no virtual methods:

```
struct Foo {
    Bar value;

    Foo() { /* do something */ }
};
```

does C++ guarantee that `Foo` will have the same alignment and `sizeof` as `Bar`? If not, then what guarantees can be given? Can some guarantees be given when I fix `Bar` to be a specific kind of type (POD,basic type,...)?

Comment: IIRC there's at least one compiler which rounded up all class sizes to a multiple of 4, so a class with just a single `char` member would have 3 bytes padding.

Answer (score 3):

There are no such guarantees. In particular, a compiler may well pad out past the end of the `value` member. They do not have to have the same alignment requirements.

You can guarantee that

1. The address of the first member `value` is the same as the address of the structure.
2. `sizeof(Foo)` is no less than `sizeof(Bar)` (otherwise pointer arithmetic would break horribly).